# Pointer to a structure as a structure itself

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I have the following snippet of code:

```
typedef int T;

typedef struct Node *pNode;

typedef struct Node{
    T item;
    pNode next;
}Node;
```

The first and the last `typedef` statement are pretty clear to me, but I don't seem to understand the second. 
Why is it defined as a structure when it's just a pointer to a Node? 
And why is it not referred to as a pointer in the `pNode next;` statement?

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
typedef struct Node *pNode;
```

creates `pNode` as an alias for the type `struct Node *`, i.e. "pointer to `struct Node`".

I'm opposed to "hiding" pointers with `typedef`, but this is quite common.

I'd write it:

```
typedef struct Node {
  int item;
  struct Node *next;
} Node;
```

Comment: `I'm opposed to "hiding" pointers with typedef, but this is quite common.` - And the questions `why my liked list does not work`, `pointers do not work` etcetc + a lots of a ridiculously erratic & bad code where the hided pointers are used. BTW this extremely bad habit is taught at many universities in the UK.